# Get filename of PDF file open and save as

Tags: vba, adobe, reader

I would like to identify the file name of a PDF file already open and copy the filename in an excel cell. After I would like to save this PDF under a specific folder with the name indicated in the excel cell.
I can do that with a word document but I found many difficulties with a pdf file. Thanks in advance for your help.
Lo